# Creating dictionary from string inside a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list `['111,"A","yes"','112,"B","no"','113,C,"maybe"']`
I would like the output to be `{111:('A',"yes"),112:('B',"no"),113:('C',"maybe")]}`

I have tried to iterate through the list, and then the string, but it ends up iterating through 1,1,1 instead of 111 as a full number.

Comment: You can iterate through the list, and for each string use split(',') to get the three substrings that you want.

Comment: For the output you start with `{` and end with `]` do you want the output to be a list or a dictionary?

Comment: dictionary! sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
In [1]: lst = ['111,"A","yes"','112,"B","no"','113,C,"maybe"']

In [2]: dict((int(s[0]), s[1].split(',')) for s in (grp.split(',', 1)
                                          for grp in lst))
Out[2]: {111: ['"A"', '"yes"'],
         112: ['"B"', '"no"'],
         113: ['C', '"maybe"']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
strings = ['111,"A","yes"','112,"B","no"','113,C,"maybe"']

# now get rid of the superfluous double quotes with str.replace
# and str.split on the commas to make a list of lists
strings = [s.replace('"', '').split(',') for s in strings]

>>> print strings
[['111', 'A', 'yes'], ['112', 'B', 'no'], ['113', 'C', 'maybe']]

# make the dict with a dict comprehension
d = {int(s[0]):(s[1], s[2]) for s in strings}

>>> print d
{111: ('A', 'yes'), 112: ('B', 'no'), 113: ('C', 'maybe')}
```

**Relevant links:**

[str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

[str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)